# base div height on dynamic canvas height

Tags: dynamic, html, canvas, height, listener

I have a canvas element that changes in height after some user interaction.
The canvas is contained in a div. When the canvas changes in height, it currently overflows the div vertically.

Can I add a (javascript or jquery) listener (or something like that) to the height of the canvas, that dynamically changes the div's height according to the canvas height? Or is there a css way to let the div automatically enlarge (like in a table row).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding this style to the div : height:auto;

Comment: thanks, but auto height did not work. As a workaround, I've put the canvas in a table. A bit ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I've put the canvas in a table. A bit ugly, but it works.